# How can I convert a file uri to relative path in drupal8

Tags: php, drupal-8

I'm trying to find the way to convert an uri like

> public://field/image/link-carousel.png

to a relative path

> sites/default/files/directory/link-carousel.png

(of course this is an example because public:// could have other path).

How to do it?

Code:

```html
 if(isset($article_node['field_image']['und']['n0'])){  
      $uri = $article_node['field_image']['und']['n0']['uri'];
      $realpath = \Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath($uri);
      $path = str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/', '', $realpath);   
}
```

here on printing `$uri` will get public://field/image/link-caribbean-carousel-epic-press-release.png.on printing `$realpath` it gives a blank page.

Comment: This is a duplicate of drupal stack exchange, see answer here https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/193869/get-the-real-path-of-a-file

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Taken from https://gist.github.com/illepic/fa451e49c5c43b4a1742333f109dbfcd:

```
// public://images/blah.jpg
$drupal_file_uri = File::load($fid)->getFileUri();
// /sites/default/files/images/blah.jpg
$image_path = file_url_transform_relative(file_create_url($drupal_file_uri));
```

Comment: This can now be simplified to `$image_path = File::load($fid)->createFileUrl()` to get the relative file path or `$image_path = File::load($fid)->createFileUrl(FALSE)` to get the absolute file path.

Answer (score 2):

```
/** @var Drupal\file\Entity\File $file */
$file = // get file.
$file->createFileUrl(TRUE); // to get relative path
$file->createFileUrl(FALSE); // to get absolute path https://
```

Link : https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21src%21Entity%21File.php/function/File%3A%3AcreateFileUrl/8.7.x

Answer (score 1):

Since Drupal 9.3 you can do:

```
$relativePathToFile = \Drupal::service('file_url_generator')->generateString($thumbnailUri);
```

See: https://www.drupal.org/node/2940031

Answer (score 0):

Use [FileSystem::realpath()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21File%21FileSystem.php/function/FileSystem%3A%3Arealpath/8.2.x) to convert from sream-wrapped URIs:

```
use Drupal\Core\File\FileSystem;

//$realpath = drupal_realpath($uri); // D7, D8 deprecated
$realpath = FileSystem::realpath($uri);
$path = str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/','',$realpath);
```

UPD: For some reason the above example is not valid, we need to use file_system service instead:

```
  $uri = $node->field_document->entity->getFileUri();
  $realpath = \Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath($uri);
  $path = str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/', '', $realpath);
```

Comment: updated code also not working.i will update the code that iam working on

Comment: @MobyM, the $uri = $node->field_document->entity->getFileUri(); string is here just to have a general idea on how to get uri form the node's file field (as most common use-case), I'm not aware of your filed names and variables to craft ready-to use snippet for you...

Comment: It' s not about field names and variables.what ever the variable may be $uri must be like public://field/image/link-carousel.png.your mentioned code  $realpath = \Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath($uri);
  $path = str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/', '', $realpath); these lines should be correct with it.

Comment: The string \Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath($uri) is totally fine, you can find it in core and contrib modules.
Refer to https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21file.inc/function/drupal_realpath/8.2.x and https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!File!FileSystem.php/function/FileSystem%3A%3Arealpath/8.2.x for documentation. The only guess I have why you're getting white screen is unreadable/inexistent file at public://field/image/link-caribbean-carousel-epic-press-release.png

Comment: Please provide more info on where and how you're using this snippet.

Comment: please refer the url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47749731/attaching-image-files-to-nodes-programmatically-in-drupal-8